# Raspberry pi 3 a+ stretch and huawei e3372h-153 port forwarding

Tags: usb, port-forwarding, modem, pi-3a+

At the moment I was able to get internet on my raspberry pi 3a+ with Huawei e3372h-153, a 4G LTE USB-dongle. 
When I enter address `http://192.168.8.1` it gives me a config web page of a dongle.
I changed [APN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Point_Name) there to the one that service provider gave me to get static IP address. On USB dongle's web page I can see correct WAN static IP address that was assigned from service provider. But I can't reach anything from out side. And there is no port forwarding on USB modem web page.

If I put this USB modem to my router and forward ports to Raspberry Pi, everything works fine.

Is there anyway to reach my raspberry if I connect USB dongle to raspberry USB port?

Added more info:

If I plug this USB dongle to my windows 10 PC it works fine, brings IP from service provider and set it as my local IP address, if I do `ipconfig`

> IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : Public IP address

And the I can't reach address 192.168.8.1

If I put this dongle to RPi I have to make a mode switch

12d1:157d to 12d1:14dc

But when I look at windows drivers there is no switch they use only 12d1:157d
How can I see what mode windows use to connect to internet.

---

http://blog.asiantuntijakaveri.fi/2015/07/convert-huawei-e3372h-153-from.html as here was mentioned that Huawei e3372h-153 can be used as Hilink modem with double NAT and Stick mode with only one layer of NAT. It seams like windows are using Stick mode and Linux Hilink...

But on that website mentioned to change from Hilink to Stick mode need to overwrite firmware. On windows I can't overwrite firmware because it is in stick mode. It seems on a new version somehow I can chose what mode to use.

Comment: What is huawei e3372h-153? A wifi or wired or 4G dongle? What is `APN`?

Comment: Its an LTE dongle 4g, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Point_Name

Comment: Unplug the dongle from your router. Does the router with port forwarding now works the same way as with plugged in dongle? Does everything then also works fine?

Comment: I am connecting to RPi from a different network, to Public Static IP address.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. For what do you use the router? Do you have a second router for the different network? Please address me with @Ingo otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: @Ingo My pc that I am testing is connect to mikrotik router that is connected to fiber-optic line. 

1. RPi is connected to DOVADO tiny router by WIFI, huawei e3372h-153 is inserted into dovado usb slot, Dovado makes port forwarding all works fine.

2. RPi wifi disabled,  huawei e3372h-153 is inserted into RPi there is an internet connection at RPi, but I can't reach RPi from out side thru a fiber-optic connection.

Comment: You may want to explain what "mode switch" from 12d1:157d to 12d1:14dc you're talking about. Drawing a diagram for the network topology that works may also help. Is this dongle a PPP modem, a TCP/IP via USB, or something else?

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev "mode switch" switch from usb memory stick where it holds drivers for windows to modem mode.  On windows it acts like PPP modem, on linux   TCP/IP via USB. On windows it brings Ip from provider and I can reach my computer from outside, on linux its more like a router with dhcp.

Comment: Windows somehow enable DMZ settings I think like is written up here https://protyposis.net/blog/using-the-huawei-e3372-hi-link-lte-dongle-with-openwrt/ "Form now on, all incoming connections are passed directly to OpenWRT" but on dongles website I can't see DMZ settings.

Comment: @ekavet Sorry I won't be able to help you on this, but at least now I understand what the problem is, so +1 and good luck.